# How to check if file hash has changed with php

Tags: php, hash

I have a php script that saves the file names of every file in directory to text file. That text file is then hashed. Here are the lines in my script:

```
$allnames = implode(",", $fileslist);

file_put_contents($post_dir . "/md5file.txt",$allnames);

$md5file = md5_file($post_dir . "/md5file.txt");

echo $md5file;
```

If a new file is uploaded, removed, or a file name is changed then the hash will change. I need a way to check and see if that hash has changed or not.

Comment: Then save the hash and check against it?

Comment: File name changes alone shouldn't change the md5, as that's part of the filesystem entry rather than the file itself.

Comment: @Powerlord: in this specific case, the md5 will change since the file contents will change with the change in the name of other files.

Comment: You probably could check it against  using `strstr` or `strpos` or any other piece of code (regex maybe) to find an exact match of a string. However, this would probably mean making a copy of the same file (at the same time) and match against it.

Comment: @Stoic Oh derp, didn't realize he was checking the md5 of the file that contained the list of files... I thought he was doing an md5 of the files themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty way (without using database) would be:

```
$allnames = implode(",", $fileslist);
file_put_contents($post_dir . "/md5file.txt",$allnames);
$md5file = md5_file($post_dir . "/md5file.txt");
$last_hash = file_get_contents($post_dir . "/last_hash.txt");

if ($md5file != $last_hash) {
  // save the new hash
  file_out_contents($post_dir . "/last_hash.txt", $md5file);
  // some file may have been added, removed or rename
  // do something..
} else {
  // no files has been added, removed or renamed, since last change.
  // do something.. 
}
```

Basically, I am storing the current hash to a particular file, and reading this file on the next iteration. If the hash has changed, I store the new hash to this file for comparison later on, and voila!

Note that, the same can be performed over database, if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

**2 possibilities without a DB:**

- make a second file and save the last filename in it and compare against it.
- include the file size into the filename or head of file and check if the file size has changed.